# Move original file to dist using gulp-image-resize

Tags: gulp, image-resizing

Currently using [Gulp Image Resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-resize) to generate different image sizes. I'm curious if there is way to also move the original file to the builder folder. Currently those don't generate out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your original images are in a folder `src/images/` and your resized images end up in `build/images/resized`. Your task would look like this:

```
gulp.task('resize-images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/*.png')
    .pipe(resize({width:100}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images/resized'));
});
```

Including the original files is as straightforward as adding another `gulp.dest()` before you do the resizing:

```
gulp.task('resize-images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/*.png')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images/original'))
    .pipe(resize({width:100}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images/resized'));
});
```